# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNPurchases.isConfigured') error in release expo APK

Tags: react-native, expo, revenuecat

I am getting an issue with the "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNPurchases.isConfigured')" error in release APK.
I am working on the expo app.
"expo": "^45.0.0"
"react-native-purchases": "^5.0.0-beta.6" // also tried "react-native-purchases": "4.6.1"

have used the below code to initialize react-native-purchases

```
Purchases.configure({ apiKey: "goog_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", appUserID: null, observerMode: false });
or
Purchases.setup("goog_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // with version 4.6.1
```

I followed the steps in https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/in-app-puchase-expo-managed-workflow/ to make it work in profile development, but the release APK I generate for uploading to the play store is giving me an error. Are we supposed to do any additional steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use the default client (Expo Go app). Using a custom dev client works fine:

expo start --dev-client
Also need to do an initialization step in the code:

https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/configuring-sdk#initialization

Response from:
https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/error-trying-to-connect-sdk-in-expo-managed-project-evaluating-rnpurchases-isconfigured-1608